# How to check if event propagation was stopped?

Tags: javascript, events

I am writing an event dispatcher in JavaScript and I've decided to base on standard js CustomEvent class. I can't find out how to *detect* if event propagation was stopped in the listener (via e.stopPropagation()). Should I rather write an Event object implementation myself?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If propagation was stopped, your listener will never be called.

Comment: @Bergi it is good to know for tests.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there is no way but to spy on the `Event.prototype.stopPropagation` function.

Comment: I wonder why does this answer has +500 bounty when just below it there's Event.cancelBubble which is exactly the answer to the question.

Answer (score 13):

### You have two possible solutions:

**The first solution**

The **[`Event.cancelBubble`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/cancelBubble)** property is a historical alias to **[`Event.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)**. But it has the difference to the function `Event.stopPropagation()` because `Event.cancelBubble` we could read like follows:

```
var isPropagationStopped = event.cancelBubble; // true if it was stopped, or false if not
```

**The next solution**

You could override the `stopPropagation` method on the base Event object and set your own flag in the overridden method like follows:

```
var isPropagationStopped = false;

var stopPropagationFuncTemp =  Event.prototype.stopPropagation;
Event.prototype.stopPropagation = function()
{
    isPropagationStopped = true;
    stopPropagationFuncTemp.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

Now if `isPropagationStopped == true` then it is stopped.

Answer (score 2):

The CustomEvent will have a boolean property [`defaultPrevented`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/defaultPrevented) if the attribute `cancelable` was set to true and the event's `preventDefault()` method was used.

```
var evt = new CustomEvent("custom", {cancelable : true});
console.log(evt.defaultPrevented);
evt.preventDefault();
console.log(evt.defaultPrevented);
```

[Browser Support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/defaultPrevented#Browser_compatibility): Chrome 18, IE 9, Edge, Opera 11, Safari 5.

**Note:** Nagy Zoltán made this important note (see comments), please understand this answer helpful in some instances, but wrong regarding the original question:

> Stopping propagation and preventing defaults are completely different things.

Comment: Correct answer.

Comment: Stopping propagation and preventing defaults are completely different things.
The question was about how to check if event propagation was stopped.

Comment: @Nagy Zoltán: No point in arguing that, you're right. I am not perfectly sure why that was my answer 3 years ago. Still, it seems that people looking for this answer came over the question above. Therefore, together with your disclaimer, I will leave the answer displayed here.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an idea: why not overwriting the stopPropagation function like this?

```
const nativeStopPropagation = Event.prototype.stopPropagation;
Event.prototype.stopPropagation = function() {
    console.log('stopPropagation called');
    nativeStopPropagation.call(this);
};
```

Where the "console.log('Propagation stopped');" is, you can basically put any callback function.

Also works for preventDefault() the exactly same way.

Soluton found here: [Is there a way to overwrite event objects and do what I prefer instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65485284/is-there-a-way-to-overwrite-event-objects-and-do-what-i-prefer-instead)

Best regards
Christian

Answer (score -11):

Have you tried ?

```
e.isPropagationStopped()
```

Or

```
event.isPropagationStopped()
```

Comment: Is this a jQuery-specific feature? I can't find any information in MDN.

Comment: Nope, it's a Javascript event. Check out it out on [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20030331/events.html#Events-Event-isPropagationStopped).

Comment: This only works on custom events, not regular events.

Comment: Theoretically. It doesn't exist in modern browsers.