# Is there a way to overwrite event objects and do what I prefer instead?

Tags: javascript, function, scope, dom-events, overwrite

I know there is a way to change the function of objects that can be accessed from a global scope. For example, `window.alert` can be overwritten to be used through `window.confirm` with the following code:

```
var oldAlert = window.alert;
window.alert = function(string) {
    var promise = oldAlert(string);
    window.confirm(string)
    return promise;
}
```

so I was wondering if event objects (i.e. `event.preventDefault()` ) could be rewritten to something different. This would be helpful if for example I had multiple places where I had to do `event.preventDefault()` and `event.stopPropagation();` together and I could just rewrite `event.preventDefault()` to do both. However, event objects can only accessed through local scope, and to rewrite event objects the way I did in the previous example, I would need to access them through global scope. So, is there a way to overwrite event objects in global scope and make them do something different? Thank you.

Comment: `function preventor(e){ e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation(); } Element.onclick = function(e){ preventor(e); /*run other code here*/ }` Note that `onclick` could be another Event. This just shows design. Or maybe you like `function clicker(e){ preventor(e); /*run other code here*/ } Element.addEventListener('click', clicker);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible, by overwriting `Event.prototype.preventDefault`, but it's not a good idea:

```js
const nativePreventDefault = Event.prototype.preventDefault;
Event.prototype.preventDefault = function() {
  nativePreventDefault.call(this);
  this.stopPropagation();
};

document.querySelector('#parent').addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('parent sees event');
});
document.querySelector('#child').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  console.log('child calling custom preventDefault');
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child">child</div>
</div>
```

As a more intuitive, safer alternative, consider passing the event as a parameter to a function that calls both of those methods:

```
const stop = (event) => {
  event.stopPropagation();
  event.preventDefault();
};
```

Then just do:

```
stop(event);
```